# How to remove special characters from dataframe using udf function

Tags: apache-spark

I am a learner in spark sql. Could anyone please help with below scenario?

package name: sparksql,class name:custommethod, method name:removespecialchar

1. create custom method in scala which takes 1 string as argument and 1 return on type string
2. Method has to remove all special characters numbers 0 to 9 - ? , / _ ( ) [ ] from dataframe one column using replaceall function.
   input: windows-X64 (os system)
   output : windows x os system

I have a dataframe called df1 with 6 columns inside another class called sparksql2

3.Import the package, instantiate the custommethod method inside sparksql2 class and register the method generated in above step as a udf for invoking spark sql dataframe.

4. Call the above udf in the DSL by passing single columnname as an argument to get the special characters removed from dataframe and save the result as json into hdfs location

Answer (score 0):

You don't need UDFs for that you can just use plain spark and define it in a function with regexp_replace.

take this example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession,DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_replace

def removeFromColumn(spark: SparkSession, columnName: String, df: DataFrame) =
      df.select(regexp_replace(
         df(columnName), 
         "[0-9]|\\[|\\]|\\-|\\?|\\(|\\)|\\,|_|/", 
         ""
      ).as(columnName))
```

with this you can use it on a DataFrame without going into the trouble of registering a UDF:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq("2res012-?,/_()[]ult").toDF("columnName")

removeFromColumn(spark, "columnName", df)
```

Output:

```
+----------+
|columnName|
+----------+
|    result|
+----------+
```